# create the multiple vnet and associated multiple subnet with list of list of object using terraform

Tags: terraform

Here i'm trying to create the multiple vnet and associated multiple subnet with list of list of object

And i'm getting the following error

This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
element 0: attribute "vnet_name": string required.

```
variable networks {
 type = list(object({
    vnet_name           = string
    address_space       = list(string)
    rg_name             = string
    location            = string
    subnet  = list(object({
        sunet_name      = string
        address_prefixes = string
    }))    
  }))
    default = [{
    vnet_name           = "vnet-app"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    rg_name             = "TEST-RG"
    location            = "West US"
    subnet              =[{
        subnet_name="snet-vnet"
        address_prefixes ="10.0.0.0/24"
    }]
    }]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each = var.networks
  name                = each.value.vnet_name
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.rg_name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **spelling mistake**.

Instead of

```
sunet_name      = string
```

it should be

```
subnet_name      = string
```

Answer (score 0):

`for_each` does not accept lists. You need to use `set` or `map` or switch to `count` instead of for_each e.g.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  count = length(var.networks)
  name                = var.networks[count.index].vnet_name
  address_space       = var.networks[count.index].address_space
  location            = var.networks[count.index].location
  resource_group_name = var.networks[count.index].rg_name
}
```

Comment: I'm new to terraform, how do i create subnet in the same vnet block